# My laptop shuts down when I close the lid even though it's set to hibernate

Tags: suspend, laptop, power-management, shutdown, hibernate

No idea what's wrong with my laptop. On the Power settings page, it's set to Suspend when the lid is closed, but for the last few days - out of nowhere, having not edited any power settings myself - whenever I open up my laptop lid the laptop boots up from scratch, so it clearly isn't going into hibernation anymore.

It's a Dell XPS 13 (9350) on 16.04 if that helps.

Thank you!

Comment: I have had this problem twice now with my Dell E5570. Cannot remember for the life of me how I fixed it the first time, but this time (after reading this post), I actually added back the #'s into `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` commenting out those 2 lines . `#HandleLidSwitch=suspend`
`#HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend`

Answer (score 6):

With `sudo` powers open up `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and look for the following two lines:

```
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

If they begin with a hash tag (`#`) remove it and set your option to ignore, poweroff, reboot, halt, suspend, hibernate, hybrid-sleep, lock or kexec. More details can be found at [Power Management](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management)

This worked for me and hopefully works for you too.

---

## Bug Reports

There are many bug reports starting in August 2016 with Linux Suspend / Resume issues. This [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1566302) has lots of solutions. One comment **#140** has grub command line changes that are confirmed to work:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'"
```

If this doesn't work, by all means check out the other solutions in this bug report. Also check out other bug reports using google search string: "Resume shuts down 16.04"

Comment: I typed in 'sudo xdg-open /etc/systemd/logind.conf' and removed the hashtags from before those two items and clicked Save. I'll let you know if that worked. Cheers.

Comment: So how did it go?

Comment: I tried the above, rebooted, logged in, closed the lid, opened it again --- nope: it shut itself down.

Comment: @bluppfisk You can search other questions on "resume shuts down". If you can't find anything solving your problem post a new question. Make sure to list your computer make and model, CPU, GPU and Operating System version.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I think that would make a duplicate question. Because I have the exact same hardware and OS.

Comment: @bluppfisk In the title the OP wants to hibernate but in the body the OP wants to suspend. If you posted your own question you can clear up which do you want to do. Also OP hasn't signed on for 6 months and will not likely respond to comments on a timely basis.

Comment: Had the same problem on a dell laptop on 17.10. This answer worked for me.

Comment: I have the same problem. This answer looks maybe worth trying. I guess I'll live with the issue for now and come back to this if necessary.

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 19.10 Linux 5.3.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me for Ubuntu 14.4, for `suspend` is

`sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic`

and then `reboot` the system.